# How to move an image with the mouse in pygame?

Tags: python, image, animation, pygame, mouse

I've written a little pygame program for moving an image by clicking and moving the mouse.

I struggle with making the moving function `movableImg` to work with my own `x, y` parameters and not with the predefined `x, y` parameters as it is now.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

white = (255, 255, 255)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

drag = 0    #switch with which I am seting if I can move the image
x = 100   #x, y coordinates of the image
y = 100

img = pygame.image.load('button.png')   #my image and then his width and height
imgWidth = 100
imgHeight = 100


def image(imgX,imgY):   #function to blit image easier
    gameDisplay.blit(img, (imgX, imgY))


def movableImg():   #function in which i am moving image
    global drag, x, y
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    image(x, y)

    if click[0] == 1 and x + imgWidth > mouse[0] > x and y + imgHeight > mouse[1] > y:  #asking if i am within the boundaries of the image
        drag = 1                                                                        #and if the left button is pressed

    if click[0] == 0:   #asking if the left button is pressed
        drag = 0

    if drag == 1:   #moving the image
        x = mouse[0] - (imgWidth / 2)   #imgWidth / 2 because i want my mouse centered on the image
        y = mouse[1] - (imgHeight / 2)


def main_loop():
    while True:        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)

        movableImg()

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

main_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: "global drag, x, y"  anytime you use the `global` keyword.. Don't. There are better ways to do that.

Comment: Yeah, i guess u r right.... I think that i'll just try to think of something better... E: So is it gonna be better if i just use more functions insted of the global variables?

Comment: pass input and ouput to/from your function via parameters and return values.

Comment: thanks for the help and advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's the code that I found on the internet and which is working as I want to. [SOURCE](http://www.python-forum.org/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=304)

```
import os,sys
import pygame as pg #lazy but responsible (avoid namespace flooding)

class Character:
    def __init__(self,rect):
        self.rect = pg.Rect(rect)
        self.click = False
        self.image = pg.Surface(self.rect.size).convert()
        self.image.fill((255,0,0))
    def update(self,surface):
        if self.click:
            self.rect.center = pg.mouse.get_pos()
        surface.blit(self.image,self.rect)

def main(Surface,Player):
    game_event_loop(Player)
    Surface.fill(0)
    Player.update(Surface)


def game_event_loop(Player):
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if Player.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                Player.click = True
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            Player.click = False
        elif event.type == pg.QUIT:
            pg.quit(); sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
    pg.init()
    Screen = pg.display.set_mode((1000,600))
    MyClock = pg.time.Clock()
    MyPlayer = Character((0,0,150,150))
    MyPlayer.rect.center = Screen.get_rect().center
    while 1:
        main(Screen,MyPlayer)
        pg.display.update()
        MyClock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the function. All you need is some events in your `for` loop. Instead of a messy, complicated function, you can simply figure out when the mouse is clicked:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:    #Remember to use: from pygame.locals import *
        coordinates = pygame.mouse.get_pos()  
        #set x and y to respective values of coordinates
        #Enter necessary code here after
```

Now `coordinates` is a pre-defined variable I made up here, in this case, it is used to store the coordinates of your mouse. When `event.type` is `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`, it means that the mouse has been clicked and the program should begin to do the code under that `if` statement. The events will only activate once, whihc means you cannot drag. I recommend that you create a function that allows the event to continue if the user is holding down on the mouse like this:

```
def holding():
    global held, coordinates
    if held:
        coordinates = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        #Enter code here
```

`held` will be a Boolean variable: it will be equal to `True` if the mouse if being clicked or to `False` if not. In this case to prevent the program to think you are clicking the mouse infinitely, add another `if` statement to check whether the mouse has been released and if so, change `held` to `False`:

```
if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
    held = False
```

also, to make sure that the function will actually register the fact that the mouse is still being held down, put this line in the `if` statement for the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event:

```
held = True
```

And finally, to run the function, add an `if` statement in front of your `for` loop to run the function when needed:

```
if held:
    holding
```

TO move multiple images, change their positions to be equal to `coordinates` or somehow related to `coordinates`. The `if` statements do not have to move only one image at a time.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i think that i will rather try to make it work as the function or more functions, because i want to use it more than once...

Comment: What do you mean more than once?

Comment: So i could move 2 images if would want to... and that's what i want. if that's ok to do...